# Photos not uploading to photo stream or syncing with iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream, sandbox

So I have a heavy question that I haven't seen asked on ad, so, or su.

**Question** -- My photos are not uploading from my iPhone nor iPhoto to my photo stream. Why?

**Background** -- When I attempt to sync photos to iCloud, the uploads obviously fail yet no error message is giving. On my iPhone, I can see the pictures sitting in the Photo Steam (queued) but then they disappear from the stream, one by one. In iPhoto, the status bar just reads "Uploading x Photos". I can create Photo Streams, but the only thing that syncs is the album, which is left blank.

All checkboxes are checked, all permissions are set, and all devices have been updated and restarted. I am using my laptop as a hotspot (Internet Sharing On). My laptop is using the ethernet card, my iPhone connects to my laptop's shared connection.

I checked my system.log while trying to upload from both my iPhone and iPhoto. Here's a dump from the iPhone's attempt

```
2/13/14 11:05:52.720 AM configd[55]: inet_set_autoaddr(en1, 1) failed, Resource busy (16)
```

And from iPhoto's attempt

```
2/13/14 11:08:01.383 AM configd[55]: inet_set_autoaddr(en1, 1) failed, Resource busy (16)

2/13/14 11:08:38.823 AM sandboxd[182]: ([52857]) mdworker(52857) deny file-read-data /Users/rjdowd/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Contents/PkgInfo (pre-plugin fstype:hfs fsflag:480D000 flags:250000005E diag:0 isXCode:0 uti:public.folder plugin:internalPlainTextImporter - find suspect file using: sudo mdutil -t 855961)

2/13/14 11:08:49.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: mdworker(52857) deny file-read-data /Users/rjdowd/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Contents/PkgInfo
```

I'm not familiar with any of those applications, but I did check the permissions on my iPhoto Library PkgInfo -- I have full r&w.

Does anyone know what sandbox is doing? And since `inet_set_autoaddr(en1,1)` looks like it's telling me my shared network is too busy to handle photos (which is bonk because I send & receive photos through iMessages all day) I suspect if I tried to connect to the internet a different way, I may see something else. But a wired to shared connection is all I have available for now (stuck in Afg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this happens to both your devices you have to go with the common factor which is your internet connection.  If your upload speeds are too slow iCloud automatically stops the sync for efficiency.  This will only be resolved with a faster connection.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. To expound: mdworker on sandbox was tied to the config daemon. When (en1,1) [the shared connection] wasn't pumping enough bandwidth out to support the required upload speed, sandbox would shut down the transfer by denying access rights. Tricky trick. There is no issue now that I'm back in the states and on a higher speed.