# How do I get the status of the Mac Photo app upload to iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, data-synchronization

I do have many (ca. 59.000) pictures in the photo library. 
I switched on the iCloud feature, keep original, it is the system library.
Using macOS Catalina, I do have enough iCloud space.
On the iCloud on the web front end I see only 126 pictures as well on all other devices e.g. iPad, iPhone.
In the Photo App on the mac I see:

"59.717 Pictures and 2.477 videos, 1 object 
Updating"

[image]

What is going wrong?
Where can I see the status of upload?

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120865/photos-not-uploading-to-photo-stream-or-syncing-with-icloud

Comment: After a some time, it starts uploading.